# How much can an Uno be overclocked?

Tags: arduino-uno, performance

When running the board at room temperature (20 C) without any extra cooling mechanisms added, how much can the Arduino Uno be overclocked?

Also, what would I need to change/update to overclock the board?

Comment: Do you want to be able to program your Arduino once it has been overclocked? In that case the answer is probably 0%.

Comment: You probably get a higher and more reliable performance improvement by reviewing your code and ditching some standard Arduino libraries.

Comment: See the following [question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12/installing-a-different-firmware-on-arduino/30#30)

Answer (score 7):

With no active cooling, most ATmega328P will run at 30MHz but you will need to up the supply voltage to ~6V. I have never done this on an Arduino board, just an ATmega328P.

I provided an external clock from a signal generator.

The only way to achieve a speed faster than 16MHz is to change the crystal/oscillator/clock input for one faster than 16MHz.

As this was just an experiment, I didn't alter f_cpu in boards.txt, so all timers etc. would be incorrect. Baud rates would also be incorrect - the only way to upload code was to change back to 16MHz.

Comment: Very interesting data about the actual clock rate supported. As for *the only way to upload code*, maybe it would be easier to use ISP instead of a serial boot loader in such a setup?